# How to deserialize a jsonarray into a List<Map> in java using flexjson.deserializer?

Tags: java, json, serialization

In the client side, I have constructed a JSOnARRAY like this:

```
{"filterEntries":[{"dataName":"mainContact","filterValue":"BILLGATES"}]}.
```

On the server side (java), I can retireve the values using :

```
jfilter = JSONValue.parse(jsonFilterStr); //jsonFilterStr={"filterEntries":[{"dataName":"mainContact","filterValue":"BILLGATES"}]}.

JSONArray jFilterEntries = (JSONArray) jfilter.get("filterEntries");
for (int i=0;i<jFilterEntries.size();i++){
    JSONObject jFilterEntry = (JSONObject) jFilterEntries.get(i);
    String dataName = (String) jFilterEntry.get("dataName");
    String filterValue = (String) jFilterEntry.get("filterValue");
}
```

But the existing app is using flex.json.deserializer and I am unable to achieve the same using flex.json.deserializer. How should I proceed?
I wish to do something like this:

```
JSONDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JSONDeserializer();
jsonDeserializer.use(null, List.class);
List<Map<String,String>>    lMap= (List<Map<String,String>>)jsonDeserializer.deserialize(params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the top object that wraps the array.  You have to handle that as well.  You have to tell it to expect a Map inside the List.  To do that you have to specify the type contained in the list by using the path expression "values".

```
Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> result = new JSONDeserializer<Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>>()
    .use("values",List.class)
    .use("values.values", Map.class)
    .deserialize( json);

List<Map<String,String>> filterEntries = result.get("filterEntries");
```

**Updated**: Add the new keyword, and made the generic types on the right match the left.

Comment: There seems to be a couple issues with the code above, I'm sure because it wasn't run or something.  But you do need a "new" before JSONDeserializer.  I also get an error that it "cannot convert from List<String> to Map<String,List<String>>"

Also, I'm attempting something like this but a little less complicated: {"title":["a","b","c"]}

'code'    
Map<String, List<String>> result = new JSONDeserializer<??>

Comment: Map<String,List<String>> reuslt = new JSONDeserializer<Map<String,List<String>>>().use("values", List.class).deserialize(json);